# Is $x^2 +9$ irreducible over $Z_{61}$? Over $Z_{71}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Going through this problem I think that $x^2 +9$ is irreducible in both $Z_{61}$ and $Z_{71}$.  My reasoning is:  there are no factors such that $x^2$ mod $61 = -9$ and $x^2$ mod $71 = -9$.  Am I going in the right direction or is there another direction I should be going in?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about $x=28$?

Comment: A quadratic polynomial (over a field) is irreducible it has no zeros over the ground field.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $x^2 +9 = x^2 +3^2$ is reducible mod $p$ iff it has a root iff $x^2+1$ has a root iff $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

The same argument works for $x^2+a^2$, for $a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
x^2+9=(x -28)(x + 28)
$$
over $\mathbb{F}_{61}$. In the other case it is irreducible, because $-9$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $71$.